# Translation Excel format for equation to mathematical notation

Tags: notation

This maybe a dumb question, but how does the formula y(x)=6.17E-04e^1.92x
(which Excel has given me for a fitting) can be translated into mathematical notation?

I have tried several interpretations and none of them were correct. Also tried using https://www.wolframalpha.com/ but their interpretation does not seem correct. When I say that it does not seem correct I mean that the value for $y(x=1)$ should be $≈ 3.7$.

Does anybody have a simple answer for this?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: At $x=1$ I get $y \approx 0.004208$ from [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6.7*10%5E%28-4%29*e%5E1.92).  You need to check your expected value for $y$.

Comment: You are correct, what I was looking for was the correct expression for which we get y(~3.7) = 1, and not y(1) = ~3.7. Apologies for my mistake.

Comment: @islamm:  to get multicharacter exponents, enclose them in braces, so e^{1.92x} gives $e^{1.92x}$.  Here I think we should leave the text as Excel formats it so people can see the question.

Answer (score 1):

$$6.17\times10^{-4} \times e^{1.92x}$$

Another possibility is $6.17\times10^{-4} \times e^{1.92}\times x$, what you have written is ambiguous in this sense.

The E is called scientific notation and $e$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: The first is correct, but you should point out that this does not evaluate to anything like what OP expects at $x=1$.  We also usually use \cdot for multiplication instead of \times

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that $e^{1.92x}$ is essentially $6.82^x$.  But you need to look at the chart to see whether the exponential curve fitting is actually any good - it is often hopeless at the extremes

Comment: Thank you, the first above expression worked just fine. It was indeed because of the ambiguity that I asked the question; I didn't know which one was correct. The given expression, "y(x)=6.17E−04e1.92x" was the written one the software gave me.